# Best solution for get json results from third party api?

Tags: templating, json

I need to get blog posts from hubspot api using this approach. 
http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/blogv2/get_blog_posts

Since craft uses twig I'm unable to use php in the templates, so I thought I could just use jQuery getJson but this causes a cross origin request blocked error.

So is creating a plugin and using php my only option to get json results from an api call?

Has anyone used hubspot api?

Answer (score 4):

This works great for templates too: https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe

Just tested it for a RSS feed, but apparently it also supports JSON.

The RSS example:

```
{% set params = {
    url: 'http://url.to/feed.rss',
    type: 'rss',
    element: 'item',
    cache: 60,
} %}

{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}
{% for node in feed %}
    Title: {{ node.title }}
    Publish Date: {{ node.pubdate }}
    Content: {{ node.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks I will have to check that out, for now I decided to just use .get using an rss url which seems to be working fine. I am thinking about just using this rss feed url, and creating a matrix field for the category example url from hubspot http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/rss.xml so field for category to replace marekting with what ever category they want, then a field for number of post to display which I can check in the loop. Using this way I can create a matrix field and then dynamically display these posts etc.